# JavaScript+JQuery: Записать в память DOM со всеми дочерними элементами

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Моя задача - выполняя адаптивную вёрстку, с помощью JS+JQuery записать в значение переменной весь ниже приведённый ненумерованный список с целью затем поместить его после `<header>` (покажу его с окружающими тегами):

```
<header> 
    <div class="centering">
    <h1> Пример сайта </h1>

    <ul id="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню2-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Если сделать это с помощью `.html("#main-menu")`, то скопируется только дочерние по отношению к `<ul>` элементы. Тогда я попытался использовать `.parent`:

```
var MainMenuContents=$("#main-menu").parent().html();
```

Однако тогда вместе со списком по непонятной причине в переменную записывается и заголовок . Можно ли этого избежать? По возможности, прошу Вас не присваивать класса или идентификатора тэгу `<header>` (а блоков-центровщиков `.centering` у меня на странице несколько).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ох, не забывайте что `jQuery` лишь **помогает** `JS`, совершенно **не** заменяя его.
Причина Вашего провала проста: предок для списка - это `header`, блоки `div` и `h1` - соседи.

```js
$(function(){
  // Берём HTMLUListElement из коллекции jQuery
  // И используем встроенное свойство получения полного кода элемента
  console.info($('#main-menu')[0].outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header> 
    <div class="centering">
    <h1> Пример сайта </h1>

    <ul id="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню2</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню2-1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню2-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li><a href="#">ПунктМеню3</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. К сожалению, не удалось нагуглить по поводу HTMLUListElement до такой степени, чтобы понять, как это применять. Вы бы не могли показать, как записать приведённый выше ненумерованный список в значение переменной?

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, это просто название `DOM`-элемента для списка. `var MainMenuContents = $('#main-menu')[0].outerHTML;`.

Comment: Хорошо, на этом проблема решена. Спасибо Вам большое за то, что Вы потратили время на этот вопрос!

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, всегда пожалуйста, примите ответ как верный (галочка под репутацией ответа).